# "Easy" triangle problem (hight school)

Tags: triangles

Can someone give me a hint to this "easy" problem?
In the triangle ABC, we have: DE || BC, FE||DC, AF=1, FD=2, find DB=?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

1) $$FE||DC \Rightarrow\frac{AF}{FD}=\frac{AE}{EC}=\frac{1}{2}$$
2) $$\frac{AD}{DB}=\frac{AE}{EC}=\frac{1}{2}$$
Hence, $BD=2AD=6$

Comment: @5xum: I edited

Comment: Thank you very much! B.t.w. does this first rule have a special name?!

Comment: Thales' theorem